# How can I hide the header bar in my Angular 17 PWA on desktop?

Tags: angular, typescript, progressive-web-apps

I have created a demo app,  which I'd like to be a PWA on desktop that is full screen without a header.

[image: Example of the header]

I have set the manifest param to fullscreen.

```
{
      "name": "projectname",
      "short_name": "projectname",
      "theme_color": "#4D22C6FF",
      "background_color": "#4D22C6FF",
      "display": "fullscreen",
      "scope": "./",
      "start_url": "./",
      "icons": []
}
```

next building the project

`ng build --configuration production`

Then I host it using:
`http-server -p 8080 --cors -c-1 dist/projectname`

When i go to the url and install the app and open the installed app through the icon on desktop then it still has the header.

how do i solve this?